# Custom Akka HTTP directive to async map response

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm attempting to build a custom Akka HTTP directive that asynchronously maps the response to another. Given the following definition:

```
trait ResponseFilter {
  def apply(request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse): Future[HttpResponse]
}
```

I would like to build a directive similar to this (which doesn't compile):

```
def filterResponse(responseFilter: ResponseFilter): Directive0 = {
  extractRequest { request =>
    mapResponse { response =>
      responseFilter(request, response)
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
...type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse]
[error]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
[error]         responseFilter(request, response)
[error]               ^
[error] one error found
```

which makes sense, since `mapResponse` is synchronous.

I'm aware of `onSuccess` but it doesn't seem to help matters.

Comment: What's the compiler error message?

Comment: Updated the question with the compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a bit of quality time with the Akka HTTP source, and came up with the following solution which appears to work as expected:

```
  def filterResponse(responseFilter: ResponseFilter): Directive0 = {
    Directive { inner => ctx =>
      implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext

      inner(())(ctx).flatMap {
        case result: Complete =>
          responseFilter(ctx.request, result.response).map { filteredResponse =>
            RouteResult.Complete(filteredResponse)
          }
        case incomplete => Future.successful(incomplete)
      }
    }
  }
```

If there's a better way to do it, please let me know!